# Deciding if these integrals Converge or Diverge (comparison test).

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have $4$ improper integrals to decide if they converge or diverge: 
1)$\int_1^\infty\frac {|\sin x|}{x^2}dx$.
2)$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {1} {\sqrt{1+4x^2}}dx$ 
3)$\int_1^\infty \frac {1}{x\sqrt {x^2-1}}dx$
4)$\int_1^{10}\frac {1}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}dx$ 
What I did and my answers: 
For (1), I said that ($\sin x\approx x$) at ($x\to \infty$), and since its in positive I can look at it like $\frac {1}{x}$, and that diverges. 
For (2), I said that $\left(\frac {1}{ \sqrt {1+4x^2}}\approx \frac {1}{\sqrt{4x^2}}\approx \frac {1}{x}\right),   $  (at infinity) and that also diverges, so I don't need to check the other part. 
For (3), $\left(\approx \frac {1}{x^2}\right)$ and that converges at infinity so my integral converges.

For (4), $\left(\frac {1}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}\approx\frac {1}{x^{1.5}}\right)$, and that converges at infinity. 
 I feel like I must have made some mistakes, I would love it if someone can approve/correct my work, appreciate all the help.

Comment: For 1): Note that $\vert\sin x\vert\leq 1$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. (2) looks fine, for (3) and (4) you also might want to argue why the integral exists near $1$

Comment: @leoli1 Woah thanks I messed up on the $sinx$ (for some reason went as if it was $x\to 0$), how do I check if the integral exists near $1$? do I just do limits and try to calculate the integral?

Comment: For (3) for example: $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x+1}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}C$$ in a neighborhood of $1$ for some constant $C$. Now use that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ is integrable on $[1,m]$ for $m>1$

Comment: @leoli1 Thanks for the explanation, following the same way: for (4) $\frac {1}{\sqrt {x^3-1}}\le \frac {1}{\sqrt {x-1}} $, in $1<x<\infty $. and that means the integral exists at one?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Note that $\sin x\approx x$ is false for *large* $x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Converges because $\frac{\left| \sin x\right| }{x^2}\le \frac{1}{x^2}$. It's about $0.775$
2. Correct
3. $x=1$ is a problem, too.  $\int_1^{\infty } \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} \, dx=\left[\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)\right]_1^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Converges for direct calculation
4. $\int_1^{10} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3-1}} \, dx$ converges, but not for the reason you wrote, because  $\infty$ is not involved.

The integral is improper at $x=1$

Set $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}=u\to x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{u^2}+1}\to dx=-\frac{2du}{3 \left(\frac{1}{u^2}+1\right)^{2/3} u^3}$$
The integral becomes
$$\int_{\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{111}}}^{\infty } \frac{2}{3 \left(\frac{1}{u^2}+1\right)^{2/3} u^2} \, du$$
which converges because $\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{u^2}+1\right)^{2/3} u^2}\sim \frac{1}{u^2}$ as $u\to \infty$

Comment: I appreciate all the explanation, thanks alot. I got a question about these integrals in general, for example (4), I understand now that what I did isn't true, but what I intuitively did is that I saw that at $x\to 1^+$, the integral goes to infinity, and tried to find an integral that goes to infinity that "behaves" like my integral. Is this a wrong approach? was I just lucky to get a right answer or it somehow works out?

Comment: @Pwaol Your answer to #4 makes sense if the integral is $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3-1}} \, dx$ which converges.